# view state property of text box false then will the data from text box will send to server

Tags: asp.net

i have small query as follows:

If i will make view state property of text box  false then will the data from text box will send to server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewState is about how the server "remembers" values of controls.

Setting the property to false will still send the data to the server.

Comment: @R.D. - ViewState manages client side state, from the server.

Comment: then what actually happens when we make view state property of text box false

Comment: @R.D. - It is removed from the `__ViewState` hidden field and no longer tracked.